Interrupt not triggered on STM32F401RET6
I'm working on a STM32F401RET6 card, and i want to use it in input capture mode for measuring the frequency of a signal. I'am having some issues with interrupt, because they have never triggered.
Here is my code:
Here is my code:
`#include "stm32f4xx.h"
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

uint32_t volatile value1 = 0;
float frequency = 0;

void TIM5_IRQHandler (void);

int main(void)
{
    SET_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR,RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN); //enable clock for port A
    SET_BIT(RCC->APB1ENR,RCC_APB1ENR_TIM5EN);  //enable clock for TIM5
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOA->MODER,GPIO_MODER_MODER2,0U<<GPIO_MODER_MODER2_Pos); //PA2 is set in    input mode (00)
    MODIFY_REG(GPIOA->AFR[0],GPIO_AFRL_AFRL2,2U<<GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL2_Pos); //enabling alternate function

    //setting timer
    WRITE_REG(TIM5->PSC,15U); //because i want a timer clock frequency of 10kHz, and period of 0.1ms

    //input capture mode
    MODIFY_REG(TIM5->CCMR2,TIM_CCMR2_CC3S,1U<<TIM_CCMR2_CC3S_Pos); //linking TIMx_CCRx register to TI3
    CLEAR_BIT(TIM5->CCER,TIM_CCER_CC3P);
    CLEAR_BIT(TIM5->CCER,TIM_CCER_CC3NP); //setting bits CC3P and CC3NP to (00) for selecting the rising edge
    MODIFY_REG(TIM5->CCMR2,TIM_CCMR2_IC3PSC,0U<<TIM_CCMR2_IC3PSC_Pos); //disable input prescaler
    SET_BIT(TIM5->DIER,TIM_DIER_CC3IE); //enabling interrupt
    SET_BIT(TIM5->CCER,TIM_CCER_CC3E);
    SET_BIT(TIM5->DIER,TIM_DIER_UIE);//enabling capture of the counter
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM5_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(TIM5_IRQn,1);

    SET_BIT(TIM5->CR1,TIM_CR1_CEN); //enabling counter

    while(1){
        //reading values of two rising edges




            //CLEAR_BIT(TIM5->SR,TIM_SR_CC3IF); //clearing the flag, avoiding the overcapture



    }
}


void TIM5_IRQHandler (void){
    value1 = (uint32_t)READ_REG(TIM5->CCR3);
}`

The function in the bottom is never triggered, i don't know why. I only wrote the handler function, but the value1 is always set to 0

Write a 0 to TIM5_SR to clear the interrupt flag when it is triggered.

Besides what @hcheung wrote above (and you may need also to check the source of interrupt), you also don't enable the timer (you don't set TIM5_CR1.CEN), so TIM5_CNT stays at 0, so even when capture events occur, they always capture 0 from TIM5_CNT into TIM5_CCR3.
